# using openapi v3 with open liberty

Tags: openapi, open-liberty

I'm new to open liberty but quite impressed about the feature. But I do miss the possibility to start my development with openApi v3. Actually I can not find how using openapi.yaml and to generate the stubs as well as the implementation class. Did somebody manage this?
best regards,
Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mpOpenAPI-1.0 feature doesn't have a corresponding tool to generate stubs from an OpenAPI documentation, but this would be a good feature to request from https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues

More information about this feature can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_mpopenapi.html)

Comment: Hi Arthur, thank you for your response. I could resolve my problem with your hint and now I'm able to use full openAPI v3 with some Microserver (like OpenLiberty), now it's fun thank's to your help. best regards, Igor